# Wake on WAN wont work but Wake on LAN does

Tags: wake-on-lan

I'm trying to enable Wake on WAN on a computer. Wake on LAN works perfectly, but when I try Wake on WAN it doesn't work.

Could it be that my router is ignoring `magic packet` from the Internet? I'm using **Linksys E900**. Also my WoL WAN tool is **WoL Wake On Lan Wan** for Android

Comment: Have you enabled UDP Port forwarding on the router ?

Comment: Yes, both ports 7 and 9 are forwarden on TCP and UDP. As I said, WoL works, WoW doesn't,

Comment: Have you tried doing a capture on your local network when you try to use WoW to see if the WOL Packet makes it to your network ?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, but I don't know how to do that, could you show me a tutorial please

Comment: Get Wireshark, and run it on a computer on the network while capturing UDP packets on port 7 and 9 only. I don't have a guide but I might be able to write one up later on today when I'm not at work. Google should be able to help you though.

Comment: ok, I'll try that and keep you updated. btw, don't I have to configure the router so it won't ignore magic packets from the internet?

Comment: Depends on the router.

Answer (score 0):

[Wake on Lan works from LAN but not WAN](https://superuser.com/questions/460171/wake-on-lan-works-from-lan-but-not-wan)

Common problem

WOL works on broadcast to the local subnet or broadcast to all networks (255.255.255.255) which is not allowed through routers

If it is directed to a certain IP through a port forward, something on that network like a router must have a static ARP table entry to direct the IP packet to the MAC address of the system being accessed. The device is off, it cannot respond to an ARP request to report its IP address. Cisco ASA-5505 routers are one such item where you can define a static ARP table.

Comment: WoL doesn't use IP addresses, it uses MAC Addresses. So it doesn't need to use ARP as it should broadcast it onto the network when port forwarding is enabled.

Comment: Recheck on that please, one of the methods is a directed IP WOL packet. One of the methods direct from Intel is _Wake on Directed Packet - accepts only patterns containing the adapter's Ethernet address in the Ethernet header or containing the IP address, assigned to the adapter, in the IP header._

Comment: Ok, so it can use either MAC address or IP Address. Either way, it can use MAC address, and doesn't need ARP.